Why performance of JSON.parse so lower compared to lossless-json?
Could someone explain, why native JSON.parse() or Response: json() method are working so slower than parse method of lossless-json?
I created example to compare. First of all you need to take big JSON. I used about 100Mb file. You can use this one if you want https://fastupload.io/74707474ed41dc72
Then play here https://codepen.io/MaevskiyE/pen/vYwYPEq and compare parsing time (It's in console)
UPDATED: After further investigation I found that it's not advantage of lossless-json, but looks like specific of Chromium implementation of JSON.parse method. If you will open the same example in Firefox, native JSON.parse will do job even faster than lossless-json.
After I changed long and lat values from type String to Number in my file - Chrome also started works fast.
My question, maybe someone know what is specific of implementation between browsers ? Maybe make sense to report problem to Chromium team


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    handleFile() {
      console.log("STARTED JSON.parse", luxon.DateTime.utc().toISO());
      const input = document.getElementById("fileInput");
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (event) => {
        const csvText = event.target.result;
        this.processCSV(csvText);
      };

      reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    },

    processCSV(csvText) {
      const nativeParse = JSON.parse(csvText);
      console.log("PARSED JSON.parse", luxon.DateTime.utc().toISO());
    },

    handleFile2() {
      console.log("STARTED lossless-json", luxon.DateTime.utc().toISO());
      const input = document.getElementById("fileInput");
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (event) => {
        const csvText = event.target.result;
        this.processCSV2(csvText);
      };
      reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    },

    processCSV2(csvText) {
      const nativeParse = LosslessJSON.parse(csvText);
      console.log("PARSED lossless-json", luxon.DateTime.utc().toISO());
    }
  }
});
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.4.4/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lossless-json@4.0.1/lib/umd/lossless-json.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.9/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <button @click="handleFile()">Parse with native JSON.parse</button>
    <button @click="handleFile2()">Parse with lossless-json</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>




Well if you've got a large JSON source with many numeric values, lossless-json will not perform the math necessary to create actual number values.

Please include any code here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site such as CodePen. See [ask] for more tips on how to ask questions that are less likely to be downvoted and/or closed.

You might have found a case where lossless might be faster, but their own README says lossless-json is slower than the native JSON.parse and JSON.stringify functions.... I wouldn't worry about it too much. You're focusing on the wrong problem. The bigger issue is you really don't want to parse 100Mb of JSON at once and it's much better to stream the data and parse it as it comes in.

@RyanWheale, unfortunately I cannot stream it as I understand. Data comes from single graphql response at once

@Pointy, JSON mostly consist of numeric values, you are right. What do you mean under "create actual number values"? Does it mean doesn't try to round this values or what? Thanks

The "lossless-json" thing stores numbers as strings, so all it has to do is copy the strings of digit characters without doing any actual math.

@Pointy, heh, while you responded - I wrote an answer that is exactly the same as you said. Thank you

I think I found the answer. Lossless-json use class called LosslessNumber that stores numeric values as strings. So because in my JSON a lot of numbers, lossless-json even do not try to make any math operation on it. I guess..
